# Background should apply only for first-child li only not other ul li's

Tags: css

i need only first 'li' element with gray background color. But first 'li' of each 'ul li' my background color gray is applying. Background color should apply only for the first li(My Example).

http://jsfiddle.net/fX9Gy/

Can anybody please solve the prob. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give **class** to your parent `UL`. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one
        <ul>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>two</li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent > li:first-child{background-color:#ccc}
```

Check this for more http://jsfiddle.net/fX9Gy/27/

Answer (score 2):

Add this on the end of your css:

```
ul li ul li:first-child{background-color:transparent}
```

Or give the element an id:

```
<li id="first">one</li>

#first {background-color:#ccc}
```

** **EDIT** **

You could try this css:

```
ul li{color:red}
ul li > ul li{color:blue}
li {background-color:#ccc} 
ul ul li {background-color:transparent}
li + li {background-color:transparent}
```

Comment: i dont want add id or class name for that.

Answer (score 1):

Either make the selector more specific:

```
ul li ul li:first-child{background-color:transparent}
```

Or add a class to the UL And select the first child there:

```
ul.nested li:first-child{background-color: #fff;}

... <li>one
        <ul class="nested">
            <li>two</li>
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/fX9Gy/15/

Answer (score 0):

hi please see the updated css i hope this will work

```
ul li{color:red}

ul li > ul li{color:blue}

ul li:first-child{background-color:#ccc}
ul li ul li:first-child {background:none;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fX9Gy/23/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
li {color:gray}
ul ul li {color:red}
li + li {color:red}
```

This will work in browsers down to ie 7 aswell

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add class or id something, then you have to use jquery. but you need to add class name for ul.

but without jquery, using CSS you need to add one more line for ul which is inside li,

```
ul li ul li:first-child{ background-color:white; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated fiddle. Added a class to parent `ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/fX9Gy/26/

Comment: !important isn't advisory as it might mess things up further down the road.

Comment: Want to give style to child so selector should child

Comment: he wanted it for the very first li know?